# Flutter bottom sheet overlapping other widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]I need a help regarding this issue I am facing. This is the design of the [image]app I'm building.
The problem is that the attach files button is overlapped by the bottom sheet, but I need it above the bottom sheet whenever it is shown. I tried using stack and positioned, but it is of no use. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

This is the code

```
class CreateCommentView extends GetView<CommentsController> {
  final String? pageType;
  final String? id;
  final String? title;
  const CreateCommentView({
    Key? key,
    required this.pageType,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      return Obx(() {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          body: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                child: controller.isLoadingOrError()
                    ? controller.statusWidget()
                    : _body(context, scaffoldKey),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  }

  Widget _body(BuildContext context, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              CommentTopTitleDescription(
                pageType: pageType,
                id: id,
                title: title,
                isDividerNeeded: true,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
                child: Text(
                  'Implementation Status',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 280.0, left: 20),
                child: OutlinedButton.icon(
                  label: Obx(() {
                    if (controller.selectedStatus.value.value != null) {
                      return Text(
                        controller.selectedStatus.value.value ?? '',
                        style: AppTextStyle.style14w5_2,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text(
                        controller.commentList[0].newStatus?.value ?? '',
                        style: AppTextStyle.style14w5_2,
                      );
                    }
                  }),
                  // style: ButtonStyle(
                  //   backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  //     Color(controller.selectedStatus.value.color)
                  //   ),
                  //     side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  //         const BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blue))),
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor:
                          controller.selectedStatus.value.color.toColor(),
                      side:
                          const BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.transparent),
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                      foregroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                  onPressed: () {
                    scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
                      (context) {
                        return Material(
                          elevation: 20,
                          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: controller.statusList.length > 6
                                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2
                                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                            child: CommentStatusPopupWidget(
                              commentList: controller.statusList,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(
                thickness: 0.5,
                color: Colors.grey,
                indent: 20,
                endIndent: 20,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5),
                child: CommentTextfield(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.attachFile();
                  },
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    iconAttachment,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  )),
              const Text(
                'Attach Files',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap your bottom sheet with padding Widget and give padding like this: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,child: _bottomSheet(),),

Answer (score 0):

**You can Solve this by wrapping the ListView and the Attach Files button with a Stack widget, and then placing the Attach Files button outside of the stack.**

**Code:**

```
   Widget _body(BuildContext context, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                CommentTopTitleDescription(
                  pageType: pageType,
                  id: id,
                  title: title,
                  isDividerNeeded: true,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Implementation Status',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 280.0, left: 20),
                  child: OutlinedButton.icon(
                    label: Obx(() {
                      if (controller.selectedStatus.value.value != null) {
                        return Text(
                          controller.selectedStatus.value.value ?? '',
                          style: AppTextStyle.style14w5_2,
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text(
                          controller.commentList[0].newStatus?.value ?? '',
                          style: AppTextStyle.style14w5_2,
                        );
                      }
                    }),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor:
                          controller.selectedStatus.value.color.toColor(),
                      side:
                          const BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.transparent),
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                      foregroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                    onPressed: () {
                      scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
                        (context) {
                          return Material(
                            elevation: 20,
                            shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: controller.statusList.length > 6
                                  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2
                                  : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                              child: CommentStatusPopupWidget(
                                commentList: controller.statusList,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(
                  thickness: 0.5,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  indent: 20,
                  endIndent: 20,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5),
                  child: CommentTextfield(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 8,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.attachFile();
              },
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                iconAttachment,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              'Attach Files',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: No this didn't solve the problem for me. The status popup is still overlapping the button

Comment: i will update my answer check it now it's working fine